# Arduino printing of two-digit month format

Tags: c++, date, time, arduino, format

I have this code in the setup for my Arduino to create a filename using the date. It is working however there is a problem.

```
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

Time now;

int dt;
int t;
unsigned int interation = 1;
char filename[12];  

DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);  

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin(); // Initialize the rtc object
  rtc.setDOW(THURSDAY); // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
  rtc.setTime(21, 48, 0); // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
  rtc.setDate(10, 11, 2017); // Set the date to January 1st, 2014
  now = rtc.getTime();
  String(String(now.year) + String(now.mon) + String(now.dow) + ".csv").toCharArray(filename, 12);
  Serial.println(filename);
```

It is printing a string of the date but there is no leading zero in the month digit when it is a single digit.

The code prints this `2017111.csv` instead of `20170111.csv`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Comment and code  look like they are in disagreement. `rtc.setDate(10, 11, 2017);   // Set the date to January 1st, 2014` and not consistent with output `2017111.csv`

Comment: The Arduino code is specifically not **C** but **C++**

Comment: Just for completion: Does this also appear, when the day is a single digit?
An easy solution would be an `if(now.mon < 10){Stringwithadded0}else{Stringnormal}`

Comment: chux, Yes the code was a little off. The string needed to be set like this `String(String(now.year) + String(now.mon) + String(now.date) + ".csv").toCharArray(filename, 13);` Now the comment and code are in agreement.

Comment: H. Puc, Yes it also happens to the day if it is a single digit. I am not sure how to implement the solution you have provided.

Comment: Antti Haapala, I know absolutely nothing about C++. I thought I was writing C code to run on my arduino.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an if statement to test if the number is less than 10 and if so add your own 0.

```
String myMonthString = "";
int mon = now.mon;
if(mon < 10){
   myMonthString += '0';
}
myMonthString += mon;
```

A far more elegant solution would be to use sprintf.  This also doesn't use the String class which can do some bad things on little microcontrollers and is generally to be avoided on Arduino.

```
char fileName[12];
sprintf(fileName, "%d%02d%02d.csv", now.year, now.mon, now.dow);
```